# Testing database field types for compatibility

Tags: c#, types

I have some generic database routines.  One that I make use of quite frequently is based on code similar to [this code](https://serialize.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/idatareader-getvalue-extension-method/), but for an OleDbDataReader, not the generic `IDataReader` from that code.

I was playing around with this, and decided to test what would if I tried to (say) retrieve a value from a field, where I had input the incorrect type.  Eg: I try to get a double value from a database column that is actually an integer:

```
reader.GetValue<double>("Column_that_is_Integer_Type");
```

...and, unexpectedly, it seamlessly converts the database column integer value to a double.  Hmm.  OK - I get a usable value back, but what about other conversions?

```
reader.GetValue<bool>("Column_that_is_Integer_Type");
```

This returns `true`.  Not exactly what I want, and I get no error.

```
reader.GetValue<DateTime>("Column_that_is_Integer_Type");
```

This one at least throws an InvalidCast Exception.

Because of all this, I added the follow type checks to the code:

```
if (theReader.GetFieldType(fieldIndex) == typeof(T))
{
    //Carry on...
}
else
{
    //Raise an error
}
```

I think this is the safest way of preventing issues, but was wondering if there is a somewhat 'generic' compatibility check that can be performed?  My onward use of a given variable **probably** won't care whether '39.5' retrieved from a database that stores it as a `double` is passed around as a `decimal`, but it will certainly care if it is being passed around as a `bool`.

My default position will be to throw an error if someone gets the column data type wrong, but I was interested enough to ask the question:  **Is there a robust method for checking whether type conversions preserve appropriate data integrity?**

Eg. Integer type converted to Double:  OK.  Double converted to Integer:  Nope.
Double type converted to Decimal:  OK.  Double converted to DateTime:  Nope.

I think I've answered my own question, but interested in opinions.

Comment: Please specify the backing db as I think that can play a role.

Comment: This is Access, but I use a similar method for Oracle, and have toyed with MySQL.  I'd appreciate advice on the assumption of Access, but considerations on how it applies to others is also appreciated.